# Error trying to Find_by_id, an extra value appears (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a POST  method that return this:

```
Request Parameters:

{"cm_test_ids"=>["1",
 "8",
 "9",
 "10",
 "11"],
 "commit"=>"Create",
 "authenticity_token"=>"WiBZQcZt2/Vi2RiFdFtaXnthClLsMubXe6sAhUzOPo8=",
 "id"=>"1",
 "cm_test_campaigns_object"=>{"cm_test_campaign_id"=>"1",
 "comments"=>"",
 "assigned_to_id"=>"6"}}
```

In my controller app I get the "cm_test_ids" like:

```
@ids_selected = params[:cm_test_ids]
```

In this point I have no problem, I'm able to save these ids (1,8,9,10,11) in a relation table but if I try to do this:

```
@my_tests = CmTest.find(["id IN (?)", @ids_selected])
```

I get this error:

```
"Couldn't find all CmTests with IDs (0,1,8,9,10,11) (found 5 results, but was looking for 6)"
```

The value "0" it doens't exits, I've print the array @ids_selected and I dont see it, I dont know why always in the IDs array is added a "0" in the first position, any idea?

Comment: dont have any idea why you are getting a 0 but my best guess is there's a nil at the first part of the array.  as for your error, you can skip it by replace `find` with `where` `CmTest.where('id IN (?)', @ids_selected)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CmTest.find_all_by_id(@ids_selected)
```

Comment: The error is "solved" using
    CmTest.find_all_by_id(@ids_selected)
but find return nil, I think I found the problem, the query generated have a lot of "\n" :
    SELECT * FROM `cm_tests` WHERE (`cm_tests`.`id` IN ('id IN (?)','--- \n- \"1\"\n- \"8\"\n- \"9\"\n- \"10\"\n- \"11\"\n'))

Answer (score 0):

Rails generates a hidden field before every multi-select:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5402

It looks like the blank string is being cast to an integer somewhere, which would give you a zero. You might need to strip this out of your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The error is "solved" using

```
CmTest.find_all_by_id(@ids_selected)
```

but find still return nil, I think I found the problem, the query generated have a lot of "\n" :

```
SELECT * FROM `cm_tests` WHERE (`cm_tests`.`id` IN ('id IN (?)','--- \n- \"1\"\n- \"8\"\n- \"9\"\n- \"10\"\n- \"11\"\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try

```
CmTest.where(id: @ids_selected )
```